# Can I have a generic rule to map subdomains to directories?

Tags: htaccess, subdomain, subdirectory

I have these rulesets which are working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.city$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.city/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.city$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.city%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

I have a certificate that will work with any number of subdomains.  I can map subdomains onto subdirectories in cpanel.  But I will eventually have many of these. How can I have a generic rule in **.htaccess** to map a subdomain to the same named subdirectory ?

For example

```
https://plumber.example.city
```

to

```
https://example.city/plumber
```

After reading and trying to follow [Appache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html) I came up with this, but it fails to redirect.  It also takes a bit long so I think it may be looping

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.city$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.city/%1 [L,QSA]
```